# How to store HTML in a PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to store HTML into an array in PHP so that I can than pass it to json_enocde. When I try:

```
$page_data = array();
$page_data['title'] = "This is a test";
$page_data['content'] = <page content>; // <page content> is just a placeholder

print_r($page_data);
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [title] => This is a test
    [content] => 
)
<page_content>
```

Any ideas how to fix this. I'm guessing it has something to do with quotes messing things up but I've tried using addslashes and such and nothing seems to resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just realized that the library I was calling to get the data I wanted to put into the array just outputs straight to the browser so I ended up using ob_start and ob_get_clean() to get the data into a string.

Answer (score 1):

As a string:

```
$page_data['content'] = '<page content>';
```

Wrap it into single quotes, so that you don't have problems with double quotes in attributes:

```
$page_data['content'] = '<a href="page.php">Page</a>';
```

Example:

```
$page_data = array('title' => "This is a test",
                   'content' => '<a href="page.php">Page</a>');

echo json_encode($page_data);
```

gives:

```
{"title":"This is a test","content":"<a href=\"page.php\">Page<\/a>"}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could encode it with rawurlencode() then in javascript decode it with unescape()